# HAProxy create new sessions in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, haproxy, session

I'am using HAProxy 1.5.18 on CentOS 7.3 and Tomcat 8.

HAProxy create a lot of sessions (more 350) on my Tomcat Server! Every 10 seconds, a new session is created.
 I think it is this line :

```
 option httpchk OPTIONS /
```

How can I stop the creation of session on Tomcat ?

Thank you,

Comment: Session is created when your code calls `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(true)` for the first time or in every call to JSP page implicitly creates a new session if there is no session yet. This can be turned off with the `session='false'` page directive.

Comment: Hi Frederico, Thanks for your answer... but where I can do this ? In HAPRoxy ?

Comment: It's OK, in the access log, i've got a 302 code... so i change my option to /login.html (real page) and now I've got code 200 and the number of session don't increase...